# Как проверить наличие выбранных данных в DataGrid при добавлении?

Tags: c#, winforms, visual-studio, datagridview, access

Как сделать условие, чтобы при добавлении записи, если сотрудник уже имеется в таблице вывести сообщение "**Сотрудник занят**"?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Этим кодом добавляю данные

```cs
if (textBox1.Text == "" || dateTimePicker1.Text == "" || comboBox1.Text == "" ||
    comboBox2.Text == "" || textBox6.Text == "")
{
    MessageBox.Show("Введите данные во все поля!");
}
else
{
    DataRow nRow = baseDataSet6.Tables[0].NewRow();
    int rc = dataGridView1.RowCount + 1;
    nRow[0] = rc;
    nRow[1] = textBox1.Text;
    nRow[2] = dateTimePicker1.Text;
    nRow[3] = comboBox1.Text;
    nRow[4] = comboBox2.Text;
    nRow[5] = textBox6.Text;
    nRow[6] = textBox3.Text;

    baseDataSet6.Tables[0].Rows.Add(nRow);
    salonTableAdapter2.Update(baseDataSet6.salon);
    baseDataSet6.Tables[0].AcceptChanges();
    dataGridView1.Refresh();

    textBox1.Text = "";
    dateTimePicker1.Text = "";
    comboBox1.Text = "";
    comboBox2.Text = "";
    textBox6.Text = "";
    textBox3.Text = "";
}
```

Comment: Давно не работала с ДатаГридами, точно не припомню как это делается но, вообще говоря алгоритм такой: взять нововводимое имя, пробежаться по всей таблице, сравнить имя с каждым уже записанным именем в таблице. Если есть совпадение, то выдать pop-up с ошибкой. Иначе продолжить создание новой записи.

Comment: Почему клиентское приложение работает с базой? Почему корявый ADO.NET? Нужно примерно это `if (baseDataSet6.Tables[0].Rows.Any(row => row[1] == textBox1.Text)) { ... }`